# $A^2 B=A $ iff $B^2 A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given that $ A, B$ are complex square matrices of size $n$ having same rank, then $A^2 B=A $ iff $B^2 A=B$.

Thanks for helping, I am totally out of clue about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is a little different from Henning's, but really it's all the same...

---

Suppose $A,B$ are endomorphisms of equal rank of some complex vector space $V$, and $A^2B=A$. Note that $A$ and $A^2$ must have equal rank, so that $\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$, $\mathrm{im}(A^2)=\mathrm{im}(A)$ and $\ker(A)\oplus\mathrm{im}(A)=V$. Also $B(\ker(A))\subset\ker(A^2)=\ker(A)$, so that we have induced linear maps $\overline A,\overline B:V/\ker(A)\to V/\ker(A)$, with $\overline{A}$ an isomorphism, and $\overline A^2\overline B=\overline A$, whence $\overline{B}$ also an isomorphism and $\overline A\overline B=\mathrm{id}_{V/\ker(A)}$.

Now in matrix terms, if you pick a basis $\mathcal B$ adapted to $\ker(A)\oplus\mathrm{im}(A)=V$, you'll get matrices that look like
$$\mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}(A)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&P
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{ and }
\mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal B}(B)=
\begin{pmatrix}
R&S\\
0&P^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Rank equality implies $R=0$. Then 
$$B^2A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&S\\
0&P^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0&S\\
0&P^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&P
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&S\\
0&P^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&SP\\
0&I_r
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&S\\
0&P^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}=B$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** By symmetry it is enough to show one of the directions.

If $A^2B=A$ then the row space $B$ must contain the row space of $A$; since their ranks are assumed to be equal, the row space must be the same. If you choose a basis for the row space and extend it to a basis for $\mathbb C^n$, then the matrices have block shape:

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} P & 0 \\ R & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix} Q &  0 \\ S & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
where $P$ and $Q$ are square.

Now just calculate! It turns out that if $A^2B=A$, then $PQ$ has full rank, in particular $P$ and $Q$ are invertible, and the rest follows easily.

Comment: no that it changes anything but what $A^2 B = A$ implies that every row of $A$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B.$  therefor row space of $A$ is a subset of the row space of $B.$  i hope i am not making a mistake here.

Comment: @abel: Yes, that's the argument I had in mind for "the row space of $B$ contains the row spaceof $A$".